# Every time I look or looked? What's the difference?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I have some questions :

1.

> Every time I look at her, my worries and sadness would disappear.

is it about past or present?

2: In this case is it true to say

> Every time I ***looked*** at her my worries would disappear.

? If yes, what's the difference between this one and the first sentence?

3.

> Every time I looked at her, all of my sadness and depressions are
> gone.

Is this a correct grammar?

Pls answer. I'm so confused right now.

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is

> Every time I looked at her my worries would disappear.

Your sentence is in the past: ***would*** refers to a repetitive action in the past, which is enhanced by the use of ***every time***. One cannot ***look now*** at her face and cause something to happen in the past. Therefore, your sentence

> *Every time I ***look*** at her, my worries and sadness would disappear.

is incorrect.

As for

> Every time I looked at her, all of my sadness and depressions are gone.

it contains an incongruence of tenses which may however occur in spoken language. It would sound more natural if you put both your clauses in the present, in which case your sentence would refer to a repetitive action *in the present*.

> Every time I ***look*** at her, all of my sadness and depression ***are*** gone.

Note: ***Depressions*** in the plural looks odd. I would use the singular, unless you refer to different occasions when you were depressed.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Every time I look at her, my worries and sadness would disappear."

This is referring to present tense, as you're in the action of looking at someone. However I would correct this statement to:
"Every time I look at her, my worries and sadness disappear."
This keeps the sentence entirely present tense, however, **informally** the original statement is acceptable.

2. "Every time I looked at her my worries would disappear."
   This is past tense. Conditionals: "looked", "would".
3. "Every time I looked at her, all of my sadness and depressions are gone."
   Grammatically incorrect.
   Corrected to: "Every time I looked at her, all of my sadness and depression would go away."
   Conditionals are again "looked" and "would".

Note: since we "looked" at her (past tense) it is implied that "would" is past tense as well, even though "would" can be used as future tense as well.